# Loading Swift Main Storyboard and View Controller from Framework

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

I would like to have my Swift Project load it's main Storyboard and View Controller from a Framework rather than the project itself.

Is this possible?

All help welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have long since resolved your issue, but posting the answer here in case it's useful to someone else coming across it from Google.

You can specify another storyboard as the main storyboard by selecting your project from the navigator, selecting the app target from the left panel and going into the 'Info' tab. There is a setting there for "Main storyboard base file name."

For your specific issue, that's probably not what you want though. Instead, open your app's Main.storyboard, highlight the view controller, open the Identity Inspector, and set the Class to the one from your framework. To get this to work for my project, I actually had to delete the existing Main.storyboard, create a new one, drop a View Controller on it, and set "Is Initial View Controller" from the Attributes Inspector first.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer :

Let's assume you have a framework called myLogin with a storyboard with id "frameworkStoryboard" and a view controller with id "login".
You would

```
import myLogin
```

to load your framework and then put in your code

```
    let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "frameworkStoryboard", bundle: nil) as NSStoryboard
    let loginViewController = storyBoard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("login") as! NSViewController
    view.window?.contentViewController = loginViewController
```

to load your storyboard and corresponding view.

Basically you could use variables for both names (storyboard and controller) instead of just writing it down.
The example is for osx, the only difference for iOS would be using UIViewController instead of NSViewController, same goes for the storyboard, also you would not present the controller the same way on iOS (this example will switch the current windows content view instead of presenting it.

Comment: Where would that code go? At the moment I don't see any place in the generated code where the main story board and view controller are loaded.

The reason to do it? I have 10 apps that all have the same main screen with the same behaviour. It would be good to put this code in a Framework so that any changes would ripple to a number of projects. Otherwise I would have to make the same changes in all 10 projects.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Will go whenever you want it to. 
What do you mean by main storyboard loaded? It is an object not a view.
If they have the exact same screen with same behaviour you don't want to put things in the main storyboard, what you want is create a protocol (a delegate actually) with his own storyboard, syntax will be the same, just the name will change.

Comment: If there were a number of Story boards and ViewControllers in a Project, how can you specify which loads when your App launches?

Comment: I think you may have a wrong idea about how OOC programming works.
You don't specify anything except when you instantiate a class, also you don't want to try to load external objects from your framework, that's not how you're suppose to do things, told you that on previous com

Comment: Let me focus my question more cleary...

What steps to I need to take to ensure that when my app loads, that the Storyboard and View Controller from a Framework (not the project) are used?

I am new to Swoft and XCode, so any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Import your framework in the file it is needed and instantiate things like i did above, that's all you have to do.
If you're trying to use something that is not currently in your project you sould have a build error

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer to correspond to what you're looking for, would you validate it?